# random math quiz human verification

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to  write a simple anti bot random math quiz to prevent some bot registration into my website, i need only help with an eventlistener, to clarify:

i want that when a human write the correct answer, automatically the button for signup is showed (without submission button) (onkeyup? onkeydown?) i can't find the right solution.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uxrv5zch/

```js
var minimum = 1;
var maximum = 10;
var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;
var qanswer = int1 + int2;

let hideSignup = document.getElementsByClassName('Button Button--primary Button--block')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';

function fire() {
  var uanswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
  if (uanswer === qanswer) {
    hideSignup = document.getElementsByClassName('Button Button--primary Button--block')[0].style.visibility = '';

  } else {
    alert("WRONG! Don't snooze during math class!")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Modal-body">
  <div class="LogInButtons"></div>
  <div class="Form Form--centered">
    <div class="Form-group"><input class="FormControl" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"></div>
    <div class="Form-group"><input class="FormControl" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
    <div class="Form-group"><input class="FormControl" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
    <div class="quizcontainer">
      <h3>Random Math Quiz</h3>
      <h4 id="question">1 + 1</h4><input class="FormControl" type="text" name="answer" id="answer"></div>
    <div class="Form-group"><button class="Button Button--primary Button--block" type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;"><span class="Button-label">Sign Up</span></button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone trying to crawl your site would defeat this in about 30 seconds

Comment: Use Captcha, any bot can read the html, parse it, and return the solution.

Comment: You should use an actual [recapture mechanism like googles](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/)

Comment: actually i have hcaptcha but i have spammer into my forum, thats the reason i want to add an extra verification, maybe with question and answer that are not numbers?

Comment: Captcha for anti-spam would still work and would prove to be more effective.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uxrv5zch/

Comment: If this spammer is defeating your capture what makes you think they won't be able to defeat this naïve implementation of a re-capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an onchange listener to the input element. So whenever the value of the input element changes, the fire function will be triggered.

```js
const answer = document.getElementById('answer');

answer.addEventListener('change', fire);

function fire(e) {
  var uanswer = e.target.value;
  if (uanswer == qanswer) {
    hideSignup = document.getElementsByClassName('Button Button--primary Button--block')[0].style.visibility = '';

  } else {
    alert("WRONG! Don't snooze during math class!")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quizcontainer">
  <h3>Random Math Quiz</h3>
  <h4 id="question"></h4>
  <input className="FormControl" type="text" name="answer" id="answer" />
</div>
```

Comment: your code above doesn't work on my fiddle, maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: I checked it and it throws an alert message right! Well it is because the uanswer has a type of string and qanswer has a type of integer so '===' will result in false because the type mismatch. just use '==' instead of '===' in the if statement. Thanks let me know if it works now.

Comment: I have checked it and using '==' works on your fiddle. When you type something in your input and then click outside or press enter, you will find the signup button. I have edited the above answer. And if you wish you can also replace the 'change' event with 'input' event as well

Comment: thanks bro, it works!

Comment: please vote this up, if it works